# Depictions of other aliens from Herbert's "Whipping Star" and "Dosadi Experiment"

Tags: frank-herbert

Wayne Barlowe, in his classic art book "Guide to Extraterrestrials", depicted the frog-like Gowachin from Frank Herbert's books "Whipping Star" and "Dosadi Experiment".

I've been trying to find visual depictions of the other sentient species from those books.  Would anyone be able to link me to anything?  I'm not getting any hits.

These are the species I am interested in:

- Pan Spechi - when not humanoid
- LacLacs
- Wreaves - both male and female, since they are different
- Taprisiots
- Palenki - especially their shell designs
- and several others only mentioned briefly

Obviously the Caliban are just stars, so those are pretty easy to find :) pictures of

Answer (score 3):

There are several cover images drawn by Bonny Dalzell for the 1977 serial published in Galaxy Science Fiction; Each cover appears to depict a different species from the Dosadi book.

[image: Dosadi 1]
[image: Dosadi 2]

[image: Dosadi 3]
[image: Dosadi 4]

There are also several alternate covers depicting alien species although I'm frankly uncertain which ones they are, in most cases.

[image: Goawchin] 
[image: Flying Dosadi]

[image: Goawchin]
[image: Dosadi 5]

Comment: The Cyrillic title... is "Argus" (АрГус) a publishing company? Don't recognize the name.

Comment: Argus appears to be based in Sofia. They're mentioned here; http://www.worldcat.org/search?q=%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%81%2C+Sofia&qt=owc_search

Comment: Haha. That's what happens when I can read Cyrillic, but don't know enough of the language to even tell that it's Bulgarian and not Russian.

Comment: @user14111 Vowels always confused me. I'll have to take your word for it.